# How to connect with external WebSocket connection in WebRTC - Sipsorcery Library C#

Tags: c#, websocket, webrtc, stun, rtcpeerconnection

I was going through Sipsorcery WebRTC C# library, [FFmpegFileAndDevicesTest](https://github.com/sipsorcery-org/SIPSorceryMedia.FFmpeg/tree/master/test/FFmpegFileAndDevicesTest). In this code a websocket server is being created and the PeerConnection is added to the websocket. Is there any way to connect to an external websocket server instead of creating one. The code is

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("WebRTC MP4 Source Demo");

    logger = AddConsoleLogger();

    // Initialise FFmpeg librairies
    SIPSorceryMedia.FFmpeg.FFmpegInit.Initialise(SIPSorceryMedia.FFmpeg.FfmpegLogLevelEnum.AV_LOG_FATAL, LIB_PATH);

    // Start web socket.
    Console.WriteLine("Starting web socket server...");
    var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), WEBSOCKET_PORT);
    // var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer("ws://localhost:8081");
    webSocketServer.AddWebSocketService<WebRTCWebSocketPeer>("/", (peer) => peer.CreatePeerConnection = CreatePeerConnection);
    webSocketServer.Start();

    Console.WriteLine($"Waiting for web socket connections on {webSocketServer.Address}:{webSocketServer.Port}...");
    Console.WriteLine("Press ctrl-c to exit.");

    // Ctrl-c will gracefully exit the call at any point.
    ManualResetEvent exitMe = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate (object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        exitMe.Set();
    };

    // Wait for a signal saying the call failed, was cancelled with ctrl-c or completed.
    exitMe.WaitOne();
}
```

I want to connect to an external websocket server instead of creating one.